# navigate between multiple windows in titanium

Tags: iphone, window, titanium

Let's assume I have 3 files `Window1.js`, `Window2.js` and `Window3.js`.

I can navigate from `Window1` to `Window2` and from `Window2` to `Window3` with no problem.

When I want to come back from window3 to window2 I do: `window3.close();`
Now I'm on window2 and want to go back to window1, so I did: `window2.close();`. But instead that got my back to window3 not to window1 as I wanted. Is there any way to get back to window1? Can someone explain me how to navigate between this windows in titanium?Thanks

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/drilldown-navigation-with-titanium/ refer this lin, might be help full

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have a look at this: [the wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Cross+Platform+Navigation+Controller) provides a cool video with [example code](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/Forging-Titanium/tree/master/ep-002). maybe you can provide some could to validate your problem..
the example itself is very nice since it works great for an arbitary amount of windows. it provides a stack:

```
this.windowStack = [];
```

that is going to be filset window.navbarHidden = true or led with the current window and the window will be opened within a navgroup. this provides the iphone navigation bar at the top (with backbutton etc)

```
this.windowStack.push(windowToOpen);
this.navGroup.open(windowToOpen);
```

the example also provides the possibility to get the first window, your window1. for that the stack will be flushed

```
for(var i = 1, l = windows.length; i < l; i++) {
    (this.navGroup) ? this.navGroup.close(windows[i]) : windows[i].close();
}
```

**[update]**
if you are not interested in the navbar just set

```
window1.navbarHidden = true
```

alternativly you can edit the navigation controller like this:

```
exports.NavigationController.prototype.open = function(/*Ti.UI.Window*/windowToOpen) {
    //add the window to the stack of windows managed by the controller
    this.windowStack.push(windowToOpen);

    //grab a copy of the current nav controller for use in the callback
    var that = this;
    windowToOpen.addEventListener('close', function() {
        that.windowStack.pop();
    });

    //This is the first window
    if(this.windowStack.length === 1 && (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android')) {
        windowToOpen.exitOnClose = true;
    }

    // open
    windowToOpen.open();
};
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want a navigation bar!

Comment: can you please explain me this line (this.navGroup) ? this.navGroup.close(windows[i]) : windows[i].close();  cause I don't understand it. Thank you!

Comment: thats another way to write an if-statement. you can write this a if(this.navGroup) then {this.navGroup.close(windows[i]);} else {windows[i].close();}. it checks wether a navGroup was created and if navGroup is not null it will close the window within the navgroup. if no navgroup was created (e.g. for android) it closes the window directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8430/discussion-between-adrian-and-mkind)

Comment: Can you please come there cause I have a question relayted about closing the current window...without using the back button. Please