# Opening and closing titanium windows the proper way

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

i've read that i should avoid creating windows using url and then opening them by window.open() in titanium.

- Can someone clarify why ? and what is the proper way to do so ?
- and Whats the proper way to close window also , since if i close it with .close() the whole app crashes and return back to the main window.

Comment: It depends on the flow of app. are you using tabs for windows?

Comment: well i need tabs for menu ( Home .. Setting .. Logout ) . is there anyway to make it rather than tabs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [tweetanium](https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/tweetanium). your question is a frequent problem since window management directly influences the performance. there are also [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495346/navigate-between-multiple-windows-in-titanium/9497686), may be it helps you to understand the problem. 
I also can recommend to read the [best practise](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Mobile+Best+Practices). there are a lot of nice examples:

```
win1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //load window two JavaScript when needed...
  var WindowTwo = require('ui/WindowTwo').WindowTwo;
  var win2 = new WindowTwo();
  win2.open();
  win2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //load window three JavaScript when needed...
    var WindowThree = require('ui/WindowThree').WindowThree;
    var win3 = new WindowTwo();
    win3.open();
  });
});
```